# State data in functor members vs global function

Tags: c++, static, functor

When comparing functions and functors, it is often mentioned that one advantage of a functor over a function is that a functor is statefull.

However, in this code, it seems to me that a function may be statefull too. So what I am doing/understanding wrong?

```
struct Accumulator
{
  int counter = 0;
  int operator()(int i)
  { 
    counter += i; 
    return counter;
  }
};

int Accumulate(int i)
{
  static int counter = 0;
  counter += i;

  return counter;
};

int main()
{
  Accumulator acc;
  std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3,4};
  Accumulator acc2 = std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), acc);
  int d1 = acc(0); // 0, acc is passed by value
  int d2 = acc2(0); // 10

  std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), Accumulate);
  int d4 = Accumulate(0); // 10

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you propose you have it start over?

Comment: @chris: can you reformulate please?

Comment: With a function using a `static` for state, the state is shared across any/all uses and calls. Depending on usage, you may need some "reset" functionality. For a functor, you can easily create many that are independent.

Comment: Indeed, I understood now. But still, this a (global) state... So the main difference would be that each functor may have its own state versus a function has one global state. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each instance of a functor has its own state, while the static member of a function would be shared.

If you called `for_each` multiple times with the Accumulate() method, the counter would never reset, and each subsequent call would begin where the previous call ended. The functor would only have this behavior if each instance was reused. Creating a new functor would solve the problem.

Answer (score 9):

You've used a `static` local variable to store state, but there's only one copy of the state no matter how many times you use `Accumulate`.  And as chris points out, the initialization is only ever performed once.

With the functor, each new functor instance you create has its own independent state, initialized during instance creation.

Even if you provided a reset mechanism for the function version's state (for example, by moving the variable to a helper namespace where a second function can modify it), you still have only one accumulator at a time.

With functors, you have no problem developing a rule such as "prime numbers get accumulated here, even composites there, and odd composites into a third one" that uses three accumulators at once.

Comment: Thanks, much clearer now! Don't mind if I accept Dan's answer? Both answers are great but you don't need reputation anymore;-D